# Capturing back click in navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In a navigation controller app, assuming you've assigned a title to the root controller, the pushed view will have a back button with that title in the top left of its navigation bar.  That is automatic.  How can I execute code based on the click event of that back button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement UINavigationControllerDelegate

```
@protocol UINavigationControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

// Called when the navigation controller shows a new top view controller via a push, pop or setting of the view controller stack.
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

Edit:
example for a simple two level hierarchy, but can easily be updated to more)

Make your root view controller the `UINavigationController` delegate (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`) and then implement as follows:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (viewController == self )
    {
        if (lastView == theOtherView)
        {
            // Pop from other view to root view
        }
    }
    else if (viewController == theOtherView)
    {
        // push to other view
    }
    lastView = viewController;
}
```

Comment: Right but if the root controller has two paths out of it - one is push view1 from the root controller tableview and the other is push view2 via an info icon, how do I tell which view I came from when going back to the root controller?

Comment: Updated. Store the viewController param as a property lastView on your delegate class and compare. It would be nicer to use the UINavigationController properties topViewController & visibleViewController, but sadly it seems these have already been updated before both delegate methods are called :(

Comment: This does not just capture the back click, but also a pop done by code.