# Adding logic before view disappears

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller

I want to add logic for displaying an alert view when the user presses he navigationbar's back button.
But I don't mean the viewwilldisappear method. Because when I use it the previous view appears before my alert view is shown. Also I want to use some of the current view controller classes properties. But these are lost by the time viewwWillDisappear is called.
I can't find any method that allows me to do this. I tried shouldPopItem, but it is not called at all.

Answer (score 0):

`[UIViewController viewWillDisappear];`

*EDIT*

[Capturing back click in navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028925/capturing-back-click-in-navigation-controller)

`- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: Interesting. Looks like this should work though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028925/capturing-back-click-in-navigation-controller

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillDisappear`:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

This should be placed in the view controller that should perform the logic. The logic should then be placed inside of this delegate method.